# After uploading screenshot to Google Play Store, how do I download the original image?

Tags: android, google-play

I am trying to retrieve the original screenshot that was uploaded to the play store.

Comment: Right click the screenshot, copy image address and open it in new tab and save.

Comment: this does not work when you are in the developer console

Comment: don't open your Google play console, Open directly from Google Play.

Comment: it's in a webp format

Comment: Yes, that format is webp, I convert it to PNG then.